# Laravel 7:Trying to get property 'product_name' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

What I have to do???I don't understand this type error...please explain with your answer

```
use App\Product;

use Cart;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CartController extends Controller
{

    public function addToCart(Request $request){

        $product=Product::find($request->id);

        Cart::add([

            'id'        =>$request->id,

            'name'      =>$product->product_name,

            'price'     =>$product->product_price,

            'qty'       =>$request->qty,

        ]);

        return $request->all();
    }

    public function showCart(){

        return view('front-end.cart.show-cart');

    }
```

Here is my controller...I don't understand this error

My route file web.php is here...............Do I need to change somethind here???

```
Route::post('/cart/add',[
    'uses'      =>'CartController@addToCart',
    'as'        =>'add-to-cart',
]);



Route::get('/cart/show',[
    'uses'      =>'CartController@showCart',
    'as'        =>'show-cart',
]);
```

here is my migration file............................I think it's not the problem here

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->integer('brand_id');
            $table->string('product_name');
            $table->float('product_price',10,2);
            $table->integer('product_quantity');
            $table->text('short_description');
            $table->text('long_description');
            $table->text('product_image');
            $table->tinyInteger('publication_status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

here is my form ...Form where I am fetching id

```
{{Form::open(['route'=>'add-to-cart','method'=>'POST'])}}

                                <div class="color-quality">
                                    <h6>Quality :</h6>
                                    <div class="quantity">
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="qty" value="1" min="1">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="Pid" value="{{$product->id}}">
                                    </div>

                                    <!--quantity-->
                                </div>
                                <div class="women">
                                    <span class="size">XL / XXL / S </span>
                                    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Add to Cart" class="my-cart-b item_add">
                                </div>

                                {{Form::close()}}
```

Comment: $product object is null. Seems like it's not exist in DB.

Comment: dump variable $product and check.this error solved

Comment: Check if you are sending the id correctly in your request. Use dd($request->id); in your first line of function addToCart

Comment: Ziad Adeela it says null...but it exists

Comment: Amir Hussain  it says null...what it means???

Comment: Please update your question and add your `schema and the row` you want to fetch.

Comment: Basheer Kharoti I have updated

Comment: use `findOrFail` instead of `find`, and let us know what happen

Comment: i used findOrFail  it says not found

Comment: Try `dd($request->id)`

Comment: Basheer Kharoti i have tried...it says null

Comment: so your `request id` is null and you're expecting it to fetch a row for you

Comment: can you tell me why this error happens???

Comment: because your `requestid` is null that's why. Show your form from where your pass `requestid`

Comment: now what should I do???

Comment: show your form, how you post that id

Comment: i have updated my form

Comment: @m.i.shad check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've named your input `Pid` and you're trying to access `id` rather which is definitely null. Try the following

```
$product = Product::find($request->Pid);
```